# Aligning a set of equations with one equation number

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

The following set of equations cannot be aligned from left to right. Since, I need to index them just with one number, I had to use split equations:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X={}^ 2 \bar{x} + {}^ 1 z \\
Y={}^ 1 \bar{x} + {}^ 2 z + {}^ 2 \bar{w} \\
W= {}^ 1 y\\
Z={}^ 1 w
\end{split}
\label{eq: logical 1}
\end{equation}
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&X={}^ 2 \bar{x} + {}^ 1 z \\
&Y={}^ 1 \bar{x} + {}^ 2 z + {}^ 2 \bar{w} \\
&W= {}^ 1 y\\
&Z={}^ 1 w
\end{split}
\label{eq: logical 1}
\end{equation}

However probably better:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X&={}^ 2 \bar{x} + {}^ 1 z \\
Y&={}^ 1 \bar{x} + {}^ 2 z + {}^ 2 \bar{w} \\
W&= {}^ 1 y\\
Z&={}^ 1 w
\end{aligned}
\label{eq: logical 1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please observe the corrected version of the first variant.

Answer (score 1):

The prescripts are typeset in a better way by using the `\prescript` command from the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  X &= \prescript{2}{}{\bar{x}} + \prescript{1}{}{z}, \\
  Y &= \prescript{1}{}{\bar{x}} + \prescript{2}{}{z} + \prescript{2}{}{\bar{w}}, \\
  W &= \prescript{1}{}{y}, \\
  Z &= \prescript{1}{}{w}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

See [page 31--32 in the manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf#page=32) for the command syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just extracting the good parts from the existing answers and using them as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\ps[2][1]{\prescript{#1}{}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\equation
\begin{split}
X &= \ps[2]{\bar{x}} + \ps{z} \\
Y &= \ps{\bar{x}} + \ps[2]{z} + \ps[2]{\bar{w}}, \\
W &= \ps{y},\\
Z &= \ps{w}.
\end{split}
\label{eq: logical 1}
\endequation

\end{document}
```

[image]